# How to migrate Springfox' @Api to Springdoc's @Tag?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox, springdoc

Manual [just says replace](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) `@Api` -> `@Tag`. But [`@Api`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/Api.html) has `produces` and `consumes` parameters, while [`@Tag`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.9/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/tags/Tag.html) has obligatory `name` parameter. How to migrate

```
@Api(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

then?

Answer (score 1):

Produces and Consumes should be set at the API-level not only for the documentation. Springdoc deduces the same from the controller-mapping annotation for the method.

Comment: So I deleted the `produces` and `consumes` attributes. Do you know why I then need to set up the `name` attribute?

Comment: The `name` attribute is for providing a name to the tag. By default, it is same as the class name but you can override it with the attribute.